# How can i add points to correct answear?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add a different points to every question but dont have a clue how could've this happen. Like maybe for q1 is 1 point, q2 for 3 points etc...

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
qs = [document.getElementById("q1"),
  document.getElementById("q2"),
  document.getElementById("q3")
];
ans = ["q1a..", "q2a..", "q3a..."];
var qs1 = document.getElementById("q1")

grade = document.getElementById("grade");
test.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var num_correct = 0;
  var num_questions = qs.length;

  event.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < num_questions; i++) {
    if (qs[i].value === ans[i]) num_correct++;
  }


  var grade_HTML = `<meter min=0 max= ${num_questions} value= ${num_correct}></meter>`;

  grade_HTML += `${num_correct}/${num_questions} correct`;
  grade.innerHTML = grade_HTML;
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <label for="q1">q1... </label>
  <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1"><br><br>
  <label for="q2">q2...  </label>
  <input type="text" name="q2" id="q2"><br><br>
  <label for="q3">q3...  </label>
  <input type="text" name="q3" id="q3"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Check answears">
</form><br>
<div id="grade"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned version using an object

The HTML is dynamically created based on that object and the calculation is based on having data-points attribute on the elements

```js
const test = document.getElementById("test"),
  grade = document.getElementById("grade"),
  qs = [
  {"q":"Q 1", "a":"q1a..", "points":1},
  {"q":"Q 2", "a":"q2a..", "points":2},
  {"q":"Q 3", "a":"q3a..", "points":3}
  ],
  total = qs.reduce((acc,{points}) => {acc += points; return acc;},0);

test.innerHTML = qs.map((q,i) => `<label>${q.q} <input type="text" class="q" name="q${i}" id="q${i}" data-points="${q.points}"></label>`).join("<br><br>");
test.innerHTML += '<br><br><input type="submit"/>';
test.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // belongs here
  let num_correct = 0, points = 0;
  [...test.querySelectorAll(".q")].forEach((q, i) => {
    if (q.value === qs[i].a) {
      points += +q.dataset.points;
      num_correct++;
    }
  })
  var grade_HTML = `<meter min=0 max= ${qs.length} value= ${num_correct}></meter>`;
  grade_HTML += ` ${num_correct}/${qs.length} correct giving ${points} point${points===1?"":"s"}`;
  grade.innerHTML = grade_HTML;
});
```

```html
<form id="test">
</form><br>
<div id="grade"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use object array with points to that answer.

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
qs = [document.getElementById("q1"),
  document.getElementById("q2"),
  document.getElementById("q3")
];
ans = [{ ans: "q1a..", points: 2 }, { ans: "q2a..", points: 1 }, { ans: "q3a..", points: 5 }];
var qs1 = document.getElementById("q1")

grade = document.getElementById("grade");
test.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var num_correct = 0;
  var num_questions = qs.length;
  var points = 0;

  event.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < num_questions; i++) {
    if (qs[i].value === ans[i].ans) { 
        num_correct++;
        points += ans[i].points;
    }
  }


  var grade_HTML = `<meter min=0 max= ${num_questions} value= ${num_correct}></meter>`;

  grade_HTML += `${num_correct}/${num_questions} correct <br> Points: ${points}`;
  grade.innerHTML = grade_HTML;
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <label for="q1">q1... </label>
  <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1"><br><br>
  <label for="q2">q2...  </label>
  <input type="text" name="q2" id="q2"><br><br>
  <label for="q3">q3...  </label>
  <input type="text" name="q3" id="q3"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Check answears">
</form><br>
<div id="grade"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also think the best way is to use an array of objects, each object containing both the answer and the number of points associated to it.

I also rewrote most of your code, using classes (instead of listing IDs one by one) and ES6.

Keep in mind that *all JS code is always public*, and whoever knows how to inspect an HTML page will easily see all the answers to the questions...

```js
const qs = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

const ans = [
    { answer: "q1a..", points: 1 },
    { answer: "q2a..", points: 3 },
    { answer: "q3a...", points: 2 }
];

const checkResults = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let num_questions = qs.length,
    num_correct = 0,
    points = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < num_questions; i++) {
    if (qs[i].value !== ans[i].answer) continue;
    num_correct++;
    points += ans[i].points;
  }

  grade.innerHTML = `<meter min=0 max=${qs.length} value= ${num_correct}></meter> ${num_correct}/${num_questions} correct, you got ${points} points`;
};

test.addEventListener("submit", checkResults, false);
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <label for="q1">q1... </label>
  <input type="text" name="q1" class="question"><br><br>
  <label for="q2">q2... </label>
  <input type="text" name="q2" class="question"><br><br>
  <label for="q3">q3... </label>
  <input type="text" name="q3" class="question"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Check answears">
</form><br>
<div id="grade"></div>
```